# NavEE dropdown selector

Tags: ee2, entry, navee, composer-template

Is there anything that already exists that allows an author to select a navigation that was built in NavEE?

In other words, if I have multiple navigational elements in NavEE and want to give the author an easy way to select which one they would like to include in the page, is there a fieldtype available to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out this "NavEE Select" addon?

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/navee-select

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered. Don't know how I missed that... Thanks.

Comment: Crap! Just realized it doesn't work in Grids...lol